# Python implemented Gradient Descent Algorithm won't converge

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I've implemented a gradient descent algorithm in python and it is just not converging when it runs. When I debugging it, I have to make the alpha very small to let it 'seems' to converge. The alpha is like, have to be 1e-12 that small.

Here is my code

```
    def batchGradDescent(dataMat, labelMat):
        dataMatrix = mat(dataMat)
        labelMatrix = mat(labelMat).transpose()
        m, n = shape(dataMatrix)
        cycle = 1000000
        alpha = 7e-11
        saved_weights = ones((n,1))
        weights = saved_weights
        for k in range(cycle):
            hypothesis = dataMatrix * weights
            saved_weights = weights
            error = labelMatrix - hypothesis
            weights = saved_weights + alpha * dataMatrix.transpose() * error
            print weights-saved_weights

        return weights
```

And my dataset is like this(a row)

```
800 0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  126.201
```

First five elements are features and the last one is the label.

Could anyone provide help? I'm really frustrated here. I think my algorithm is theoretically right. Is it about the normalization on the dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not even sure if this solves anything, but I'd be wary of using floating point numbers. I would use the `decimal` module to prevent rounding errors.

Comment: Have you tried normalizing your data set?

Comment: @IVlad Yeah I think it may arouse problems as well, thank you for the tip!